# Webpack config HTMLWebpackPlugin with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, webpack, config

I'm using HTMLWebpackPlugin to generate my simple html files, the problem is that I want to make simple contact form on page, and for that I'm using PHP.
How can I make it work properly?

There is link for my webpack config:

https://github.com/UncleGreg/webpack-config/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: did you try without the 'minify' option ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm working on a PHP MVC framework and there is no "index.html" i can point on for the `template:` js input.